# Blurry background on a moving navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Is there any way I can get a blurred background on a boostrap 4 navbar?

I've tried the CSS blur filter, but it blurs all my div content as well. And I've seen some people using SVG to get whatever is behind the `div`, blurring that and then showing it, just like photoshop masks, but that wouldn't work for me as I need a `fixed-top` navbar so it's scrolling with the browser through the whole page.

So, I need to apply some css effect to this ´nav´, so it blurs whatever is behind it, or at least looks like it does that.

```
{# Navbar #}
    <nav id="home-navbar" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light mx-0 mx-md-auto" style="background-color: #ffffffcc; z-index: 3; max-width: 1140px;">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#"><img src="{{ asset('img/logo-menu.png', 'theme') }}" style="max-height: 66px;"></a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav mx-auto my-4 my-lg-0" style="padding: 0;">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">{{ l('hotel') }}</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#"</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">{{ l('restaurantes') }}</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">{{ l('galeria') }}</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">{{ l('promocoes') }}</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">{{ l('contato') }}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: you need to provide your code

Comment: Half question!! You need to add clear question.

Comment: check this https://codepen.io/thbwd/pen/VYbZWo

Comment: That's good, but I need it moving with the page.

Comment: in your example, the blur works on the background image, but you want something that looks blurred over other elements of your page, correct?

Comment: Correct! Like it blurs what's behind the navbar, not the navbar itself (which is a bit transparent, so we can see the blurred whatever is behind).

Comment: you'll have to use `javascript`, this won't work with `css` alone. https://bencentra.github.io/blur-overlay/

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
.nav-bar-class-name:before {
   background-image: url('http://example.com');

  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Put the image and the blur effect within a `:before` state, and then do the rest of your nav-bar styling in the normal way

```
.nav-bar-class-name {
    example: example;
}
```

---

**The alternative solution (working):**

As mentioned due to the nature of Bootstrap the above solution won't work, here is a solution without using JS:

HTML:

```
<nav class="nav-bar-blur">
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-bar-blur {
    background-image: url('https://www.fillmurray.com/1500/1500');
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;

    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
    -moz-filter: blur(2px);
    -o-filter: blur(2px);
    -ms-filter: blur(2px);
    filter: blur(2px);
}

.navbar {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
}
```

Here is my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/CodeBoyCode/pen/NLZwwd) showing the above solution, effectively the only way to do it is to have 2 overlapping "navbars"

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for me. I would have to do this in my #home-navbar, right? The :before selector isn't changing anything..

Comment: no you could just change .nav-bar-class-name to .navbar

Comment: I've tried it. It just doesn't apply for some reason.

.navbar:before {
 -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
 -moz-filter: blur(20px);
 -o-filter: blur(20px);
 -ms-filter: blur(20px);
 filter: blur(20px);
}

Comment: It doesn't seem to like it when using bootstrap for some reason - let me have another look and Iwill get back to you with a codepen/JSfiddle when I solve it

Comment: Hey @AdautoVieira - I have found a solution without using JavaScript.

Unfortunately, becuase of the way Bootstrap is set up, it has various set variables and the :before solution that I offered first went right behind the navbar so it wasn't visible. I will update my answer with the alternative solution now.

Comment: That's awesome, but here's my problem: It can't be a fixed image. I'm looking for a way to blur whatever is behind the navbar so when it moves down or up through the page, it also changes what is in fact blurred. Thanks for the attention, btw

Comment: hey @AdautoVieira - thanks for the additional information - I've got soo close, but I don't believe there is a solution to blur the background image of another div whilst using Bootstrap - the only way (in my opinion, which may be wrong) would be to build the nav bar yourself and use pseudo-classes like :before and :after etc.

Good luck with the answer man, i've asked a few people to help with the answer, I will be as glad as you to find a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the CSS [backdrop-filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) property.

HTML:

```
<nav class="nav-bar-blur">
  <content/>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-bar-blur {
  backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
}
```